# Make a form like windows 7 Move File form with DevExpress

Tags: c#, windows-7, devexpress

[image]
I want to make a form like this in windows forms. To make a user choose to continue...
I use DevExpress and i want a control or a button or a way to make something like this. For example when the user clicks a choice to be hightlighted.
Is a control for doing this or i have to do something bad styled with buttons and labels?

Comment: How about WPF, you looked into that?

Comment: Just overwrite the behavior of a groupbox.

Comment: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/TaskDialogforWinForm/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=362

Comment: Also wrapped by the Windows API Code Pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use the [GridControl Advanced Banded View](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument729) to organize such a cell layout within a row.

Hide indicators, bands, columns, etc. i.e. organize a simple list.

Handle the RowStyle event to emulate a [cell highlighting](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3511).

Handle the Click event of the required entity to respond to end-user manipulations.